# How to solve adb version error in android studio device monitor?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-virtual-device

During learning Android in Android Studio, I click on Window->Reset Perspective in **android device monitor**.
After that it gives me this error.
[image: Error Message]

My android virtual device is running successfully.
Help me solve this issue.

Comment: try kill and start adb server.. or restart machine ,Some time i am facing the same issue i dot know why.

Answer (score 0):

Few solutions i tried and which worked for me in different times :

1. Go in devices view, delete the device and create a new one.
2. Kill the adb through command line

   Before you execute the commands in CMD make sure that you added the adb tool to your Environment Variables path.

Killing adb

> adb kill-server

Starting adb

> adb start-server

other way of killing adb is Go to task manager->processes and kill the adb.exe process.

Even after doing all these if it prevails, the final thing i did is restarted my whole machine so that adb process is removed from RAM.

Hope it helped :)

Comment: I am running my android studio on a mac and can you tell me how to add adb tool to my environment variable path in android studio in mac. Also tell me in which directory I have to move to run these commands via terminal.

Comment: in mac it was a bit more simple,Go to directory tools inside Android sdk. Then click on adb file which restarts automatically.  Then start the eclipse again.